# cursor.execute fails , when the id parameter exceeds a value 10

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my remove download function . The id field in my download table is set to auto increment . When the id value is less than 10 this function seems to work fine . Once the value is 10 or greater the cursor.execute() fails.

```
def remove_download(id, userName):
    db = threadpool.connect()
    if db is not None:
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql1 ="SELECT status FROM download WHERE id=%s;"
        sql = "DELETE from download WHERE id=%s and user_name=%s;"
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql1,str(id))
            data = cursor.fetchone()
            if data[0] != Status.DEFAULT and data[0] != Status.ERROR:
                db.commit()
                return "Download started. Entry cannot be deleted."
            cursor.execute(sql, (str(id), userName))
            db.commit()
        except MySQLdb.Error as e:
            db.rollback()
            return e[1]
        return "success"
    return "db connection error"
```

Comment: can you post full traceback ?

Comment: apparently passing the id in square braces solves the issue , i am still not clear why that happens. In this manner - `cursor.execute(sql1,[str(id)])`